# Cannot find object property

Tags: qtp

I am a beginner in QTP.When I tried to add objects from a web page (Google.com) it is getting added like "Window-Google Chrome" instead of "Browser:page"like this.Could someone please answer my question?.I am starting the browser only after starting the QTP.

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome is not supported yet. Try it on IE, or Firefox and it should work.

Comment: @Jops Chrome is supported in the recent versions of QTP.

Comment: I've added a little more information about which versions of QTP support Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you selected the **Web** add-in in the addin manager

Also you should verify that the extension is enabled in the browser.

If this doesn't work make sure that you're using a supported version of the browser for your version of QTP (you can see the support matrix in your documentation).

If you can't find the supported browsers please specify what version of QTP and browser you're using.

The first version of QTP to support Chrome was QTP11 and you had to install a special patch (which patch depends on the version of Chrome in question, contact HP support for more details). All newer versions of QTP (now known as UFT) support some versions of Chrome out of the box but since Chrome tends to change quite a lot you may need additional patches.

Comment: If you have a link to HPs "product compatibility matrix" handy, add it to that answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try the above solution it should work. have you tried both the methods.
1. Adding object propertied and values to object repositories by record and run method.
2. Using descriptive programming. Using object spy hover your mouse over the object for checking its properties and value.
Ex: Browser("Name:=.*").page("Title:=.*").WebElement("Name:=Email").Set "vicky15.verma@gmail.com"

---

One more thing that I have noticed is for websites like Gmail you need to have Java Addin as these websites are designed using Java and Java Script. It is important inorder to call the methods for Java Addin.

Regards
Vicky V

Comment: The Java add-in is not needed for standard HTML controls, and is unrelated to JavaScript; that's what the Web add-in is for.